# How to send image using Discord.MessageAttachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm retrieving image data from the google maps API and trying to send it as an image through 'Discord.MessageAttachment', however it is throwing the error:

> TypeError: Discord.MessageAttachment is not a constructor
> at C:\Users\dario\OneDrive\dev\JavaScript\DscBot\src\index.js:35:30
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Here is the releveant code

```
      const latitude = Math.random() * 180 - 90;
      const longitude = Math.random() * 360 - 180;
      const apiUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=${latitude},${longitude}&key=*MyAPIKey`;
  
      axios
        .get(apiUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        .then(response => {
          const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(response.data, 'image.jpg');
          message.channel.send(attachment);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          message.channel.send('Failed to get a street view image.');
        });
```

Note that I am on the latest version of Discord.js, and this 'Discord is imported (I think) correctly:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

I expected an image to be sent to the server which I am testing it on, however 'Failed to get a street view image.' was returned alongside a terminal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest version of Discord.js "`MessageAttachment`" was renamed to "`AttachmentBuilder`". ([More Info in the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/AttachmentBuilder))

So your code would have to look like this:

```
const latitude = Math.random() * 180 - 90;
const longitude = Math.random() * 360 - 180;
const apiUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=${latitude},${longitude}&key=*MyAPIKey`;
  
axios
  .get(apiUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  .then(response => {
    const attachment = new Discord.AttachmentBuilder(response.data, { name: 'image.jpg' });
    message.channel.send(attachment);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    message.channel.send('Failed to get a street view image.');
  });
```